# Unity streaming WWW issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-components

I'm using WWW Unity class to get songs from S3 Bucket.

The issue is this, when I'm loading one song, the streaming works great, I'm getting a big enough buffer and able to play a song easily with AudioSource Clip.

The problem starts when I try to call the function twich, witch actually means, I have the need to download two songs at the same time. Let me notice that if I try to hold the second function, still I get an error ( The error is a "Red" error, but without any data about the error).

Function:

```
 private IEnumerator startSongStreaming(int playerIndex,User user)
    {
        string url = user.getCurrentGamePerformacePath ();
        WWW www = new WWW (url);
        AudioSource audioSource = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("PlayerResultsAudio")[playerIndex].GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        AudioClip myAudioClip = audioSource.clip;
        Debug.Log (playerIndex +  " :" +  www.progress);
        while (www.progress < .1f) {
            Debug.Log ("Streaming WWW PLAYER INDEX: " + playerIndex + " " + www.progress);
            yield return null;
        }
        myAudioClip = www.audioClip;
        Debug.Log (playerIndex +  " CHECKTHIS:" +  www.progress);
        while (!(myAudioClip.isReadyToPlay)) {
            Debug.Log ("IS READY TO PLAY PLAYER INDEX: " + playerIndex + " " + www.progress);
            yield return null;
        }
        //Debug.Log ("TESTME: " + myAudioClip.isReadyToPlay);
        audioSource.clip = www.GetAudioClip(false, true, AudioType.WAV);
        Button listen = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("PlayerResultsListenBtn") [playerIndex].GetComponent<Button> ();
        listen.interactable = true;
    }
```

I have no issues with the prefabs and getting the GameObjects, it works great with the funciton that function that calls this function.

Anyhow the debug.logs return a good streaming for one of the indexs, and sets streaming to 1 on the other ( like it's finished, but it never really started ).
so I get 0 and streaming ( object will work and play )
and 1 and 1 streaming ( like streaming is completed but an unknowen error and cant play the audio ).

I know it's a head to understand question, Thank ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, we have purchased Unity3d Pro version and the problem has been solved, no code errors or changes, simply works :).

So if anyone tackle with this type of problem, contact Unity3d support.